# How to get value of the field of a referenced model in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say, I have defined two models like so

```
My_CHOICE_SELECTION = (
    ('Option_1', 'Option_1'),
    ('Option_2', 'Option_2'),
)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    user_field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=My_CHOICE_SELECTION)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # Some Profile fields here
    profile_field_1= models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    # Over-ride save method
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # **** How do I get the value here for my if condition? ****
        if (<--Check for value in CustomUser.user_field_2 -->):
            # If true do something
        else:
            # Else do something else
```

How do I get I check for value of `user_field_2` of `CustomUser` model in my `UserProfile` model?

I tried doing like so

```
if CustomUser.objects.user_field_2 == 'required_value':
    # Do something
```

I am getting the following error

```
'UserManager' object has no attribute 'user_field_2'
```

---

Update

I also tried the following

```
if self.user.user_field_2 == 'required_value':
    # Do something
```

In this case the truth condition is not evaluated and always evaluated falsy condition.

Comment: You can userprofile form to perform that operation.

Comment: I am using this in django-rest-framework. I am new to using django. Should I create forms even if I am using django-rest-framework?

Comment: Use `self.user.user_field_2`? For example: `if self.user.user_field_2 == 'required_value':`

Comment: @IainShelvington If I do that I do not get the error but the truth condition is not evaluated.

Comment: @LubnaAther why do you expect the condition to be "true"?

Comment: @IainShelvington I tested to see would the truth condition execute, but it doesn't.

Comment: @LubnaAther I'm not sure what you mean by "doesn't execute". It always evaluates to `False` or the if statement is never run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239178/discussion-between-lubna-ather-and-iain-shelvington).